# Prediction mapping using temporal point data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, air-quality

I have a temporal point data set of PM2.5 from 2002 to 2017.Based on this data sets I would like to generate some prediction (forecast) maps for 2020, 2025 and 2030. What would the be the main tools to derive these maps using GIS or ArcGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.